# WPF - UI Not Updating When Item Added to Bound Collection

Tags: wpf, user-interface, binding

I have a Generic List of objects that I've bound to a custom control.  Everything seems to work OK in the code-behind, but any changes I make to the collection don't seem to reflect in the UI (even though they're working find in all the code behind).

Here's the XAML for my UI:

```
<controls:ControllableListView x:Name="lvSummaryCaseEvents" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Label="Case Events:" ItemsSource="{Binding CaseEvents}" AddButtonClicked="ControllableListView_AddButtonClicked">
```

And the code behind where I add the item into the collection:

```
_caseScreen.CaseEvents.Add(caseEvent);
//after the line above executes, lvSummaryCaseEvents (in the debugger) shows the correct number of items and the items' values are all correct.  No change to the UI whatsoever
```

The ItemSource property in my user control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(System.Collections.IList), typeof(ControllableListView));

public System.Collections.IList ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as System.Collections.IList;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And finally, the XAML for a standard ListView that lives in my user control which is bound to the ItemsSource property listed above:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Name="lvListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" View="{Binding View}" SelectionChanged="lvListView_SelectionChanged" />
```

Just to reiterate, everything works fine when I display the collection the first time around, but when I add an item to the collection, the UI does not reflect the changes made.

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Comment: What type is _caseScreen.CaseEvents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your collection to `ObservableCollection<T>`